# How do I logout in Ubuntu 17.10 with wayland?

Tags: wayland

I want to logout without rebooting the computer, but in 17.10 there is no option to logout in the top-right corner

There is only a button to lock the screen, and a button to restart or shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on your username in the top-right corner, there should be a logout option.

[image]

Alternatively, click on "*Activities*" (or press <kbd>super</kbd>) and search for "log out" (or the equivalent word in your system language, e.g. "abmelden" in German). A "Log out" icon should appear which should log you out.

[image]

Comment: Fine, that's quite hidden, especially, if you don't use a picture for your user account, then it is the last line of 7 in my case. And in german, you can click the`Super`-Key and enter "abmelden"