# How to exit and enter X session?

Tags: command-line, display, 22.04, xserver

I'm trying to install XFree86 and it asks to turn off the display, but I don't know how to do that.

What command do I do this with?

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu (22.04).

Comment: What DE - desktop environment - are you running? What do you mean by "stop X session"?

Comment: Installing lightdm is the wrong way to control whether or not your *display server* (either X or Wayland) is running. ALL display managers already do that. That's what they do. This seems like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): Instead of asking about how to control the X server, you should ask about whatever problem has led you to believe that such control is a desirable solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I logout in Ubuntu 17.10 with wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006471/how-do-i-logout-in-ubuntu-17-10-with-wayland)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04, the login/password screen is NOT run by the display *server* (X or Wayland) -- it's run by the display *manager* (gdm or lightdm).

When you see that login/password screen, the display *server* is not running nor even loaded.

Upon a succesful login, the display *manager* launches the display *server* and triggers the loading of the entire desktop.

That's one reason why loading your desktop takes a moment. Your whole desktop stack is loading.

Upon logout, the display *server* is stopped. That's why you return to the login/password screen (the display *manager*).

Comment: And how do I logout? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm new to Linux.

Comment: How to logout of Gnome: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006471

Comment: How to logout of Gnome using a terminal instead of your mouse: https://askubuntu.com/questions/180628

Comment: Okay, but just logout doesn't work for me. I want to turn off Display so I can install XFree86. If I logout this way how can I install it?

Comment: That's a **very** ambitious goal for somebody who is "new to Linux," mostly because that project has not released in 13 years; it pre-dates many Ubuntu system components and is unlikely to work for you without hours of expert help. What is the issue you are encountering that leads you to believe that XFree86 is the best solution?

Comment: I'm trying to install QJoypad which requires it.

Comment: qjoypad is in the standard repositories.  I doubt it requires XFree86.

Comment: I suggest opening a new question: "How do I install qjoypad on Ubuntu 22.04?" I suspect you may find the answers to be much less confusing and much more satisfying.

Comment: I'm actually trying to build it because here (https://github.com/panzi/qjoypad), in its repository, there's no version already compiled.

Comment: The requirement for that version is XWindows (not XFree86). XWindows is already included with Ubuntu -- you select it at the password screen when you login.

Comment: I clicked on the top right corner of the Ubuntu desktop and chose Shutdown/Logout and Log Out. So I clicked on the gear icon at the bottom right and it only had Ubuntu and Ubuntu with Wayland options. Remembering that I formatted my PC, then deleted the Lightdm I had installed.

Comment: @atila-o-grande The "Ubuntu" choice is the Xorg default (you probably are using Nvidia hardware with the 515 driver to get the Wayland option).

Comment: You're right about the driver I'm using, but will either option enable Xorg?

Comment: Friends, you won't believe it, but I found QJoypad in this [link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qjoypad/qjoypad_4.3.1-3_amd64.deb). How silly of me trying to compile it!